# Выгрузка данных с цветом в Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Выгружаются данные из `dataGridView` в Excel всё нормально при экспорте цвета проблема с белым цветом, все столбцы где есть белый цвет выгружаются черными.

**Код выгрузки:**

```
  var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { Visible = false };
            var wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            var ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
            // changing the name of active sheet
            ws.Name = "Лист1";


            // storing header part in Excel
            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }


            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * i / dataGridView1.RowCount);

                    //var range = (Range) ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1];
                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    // range.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor);
                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor);


                }
            }

            // sizing the columns
            ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            // save the application
             wb.SaveAs("c:\\APPS\\Distanc.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, MessageBox.Show(@"Файл сохранён в c:\APPS\Distanc.xlsx"));

            // Exit from the application
            app.Quit();
```

Если выгружать без цвета то всё нормально.

Стоит двойной буфер у `dataGridView`

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {

            var dgvType = dgv.GetType();

            var pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );

            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);

        }
```

> VirtualMode = false

Прошу оказать помощь в решении проблемы.

**UPD**

Вот как отрисовывает, т.е при выгрузки из приложения цвет не видимых полей передаётся как RGB 0.0.0 
[image: Проблема с отрисовкой не видимых полей]

Comment: Под отладчиком посмотрите какое значение лежит в `dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` на проблемных ячейках и какое значение выдает `ColorTranslator.ToOle`

Comment: ^ +1. Вы можете сократите пример до одной строчки (пропишите хардкодом значение цвета в одну ячейку Excel, либо спросите почему получается именно такое значение). Почитайте про [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Андрей в общем проблема чуть усложнилась, он отрисовывает с цветом первые 17 строк далее RGB 0,0,0 идёт. т.е он отрисовал зону видимости в форме 17 строк.

Comment: @Павел, попробуйте синхронно тогда прокручивать DataGridView при экспорте (чтоб экспортируемая строка была на экране). А лучше хранить цвет строки отдельно, а не в контроле